# print JSON array - steam web api

Tags: json, api, web

I've been toying around with the Steam Web API using JSON format. I've been trying to print the array output given by the API.

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $key = 'xxx';

    $link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' . $key . '&steamids=' . $id . '&format=json');
    $profile_info = json_decode($link);

    $json_response = json_encode($profile_info->response);
    print($json_response['steamid']);
?>
```

the key is obviously replace by the key given to me by Steam's generator. But this code snippet I have only returns the character `{` it should return `76561197989628470` which is my steamid.

These are the arrays in JSON format

```
{

   "response": {

      "players": [

         {

            "steamid": "76561197989628470",

            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,

            "profilestate": 1,

            "personaname": "Archey",

            "lastlogoff": 1334719151,

            "commentpermission": 1,

            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/Archey6/",

            "avatar": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/74/745b633a08937a5cf52bb44c2bdd3552f85455d7.jpg",

            "avatarmedium": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/74/745b633a08937a5cf52bb44c2bdd3552f85455d7_medium.jpg",

            "avatarfull": "http://media.steampowered.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/74/745b633a08937a5cf52bb44c2bdd3552f85455d7_full.jpg",

            "personastate": 1,

            "primaryclanid": "103582791432066081",

            "timecreated": 1177637717,

            "loccountrycode": "CA",

            "locstatecode": "SK"

         }

      ]

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you decoding then encoding json?

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $key = 'xxx';

    $link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' . $key . '&steamids=' . $id . '&format=json');
    $myarray = json_decode($link, true);

    print $myarray['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];
?>
```

Or if you really need to encode again:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $key = 'xxx';

    $link = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=' . $key . '&steamids=' . $id . '&format=json');
    $profile_info = json_decode($link);

    $json_response = json_encode($profile_info->response->players);
    $decoded = json_decode($json_response, true);
    print $json_response['steamid'];
?>
```

Comment: Not too sure why I encoded it but, trying your first example gave me the error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: In which line? I copied your example json file in my computer and tried this: `<?php
    $link = file_get_contents('your_example.json', true);
    $myarray = json_decode($link, true);
    print $myarray['response']['players'][0]['steamid'];

?>` . It works.

Comment: also you need to add another brace at the end of the json file.

Comment: `print($myarray['response']['players'][0]['steamid']);` and you should add a zero here. Sorry for mistake.

Comment: Even with the [0] it still gives the same error on line 8, the print line.

Comment: Can you please change the print line to `var_dump($myarray);`, run the program and paste the result to http://pastebin.com/ and give me the link? I can't understand it. The code above works perfectly with your example json in my machine. I'm getting suspicious about invalidity of json response returning from that api.

Comment: Ah, Sorry! I looked over your code again, I didn't have 'true' as the second paramter for json_decode. It works now, thanks :)