# How to retrieve current players for each game with Steam API?

Tags: json, api, steam, steam-web-api

I was wondering how is data retrieved in this site for example? http://steamcharts.com/

I've done a ton of research with https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API and the only info I found was a suggestion to parse a website containing these data?

Any insight would be great, thanks

Comment: May I suggest looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221101/print-json-array-steam-web-api You'd need to call the GetPlayerSummaries method to return the data. You can also find a pretty extensive blog post on this subject here: http://vartree.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/harvesting-data-from-steam-community-api.html Finally - be careful on your usage of tags, some may argue that this question doesn't related to jQuery specifically. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, however I am after global stats. The only way to do it with GetPlayerSummaries would be getting stats for each SteamID (which is limited to 100). Is there a way to parse and get data from http://steamcharts.com/? Will remove some tags, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

Found it in a hidden API for whoever else is looking for a solution :) https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetNumberOfCurrentPlayers/v1/